# Drivers not working after Update to 5.4.0-1059-aws

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo

Since I updated my system to 5.4.0-1059-aws my hardware is not working anymore.
(Same is for the update to 5.4.0-1060-aws).
The last version, everything was working, is 5.4.0-1057-gcp.
What is working:

- the keyboard
- the display
- an external usb mouse

What is not working anymore:

- the touchpad
- wifi
- ethernet
- bluetooth
- USB tethering with my Android phone

So currently I have no internet connection in these versions.
I have an Lenovo Yoga C740 and I remember that I had to install the driver for the wifi module manually, but the touchpad and ethernet were working from the beginning on.
My current workaround is to manually select the 5.4.0-1057-gcp version in the boot menu, but that's far from ideal (and I don't know if there are any problems doing this).
So my questions would be:

1. How can I fix all the drivers for the newest ubuntu versions?
2. How can I return to the earlier version 5.4.0-1057-gcp?

If you need any console output, just let me know.

Many thanks in advance

Nik

---

Edit:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections
...
linux-base     install
linux-firmware     install
linux-generic-hwe-18.04    install
linux-headers-5.3.0-62    install
linux-headers-5.3.0-62-generic   install
linux-headers-5.4.0-91-generic   install
linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04   install
linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-42   install
linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-47   install
linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-48   install
linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-90   install
linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-91   install
linux-image-4.15.0-1055-gke   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1056-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1058-gke   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1059-gke   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1059-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1060-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1063-aws   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1063-gke   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1064-gke   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1066-gke   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1067-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1069-gke   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1069-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1070-gke   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1071-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1074-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1075-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1076-oem   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1079-gke   install
linux-image-4.15.0-1080-oem   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1081-oem   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1087-oem   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1091-oem   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1093-oem   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1096-oem   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1097-oem   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1102-kvm   deinstall
linux-image-4.15.0-1103-kvm   install
linux-image-5.0.0-1033-gcp   deinstall
linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.0.0-37-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1017-aws   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1018-gcp   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1019-aws   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1020-gcp   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1023-aws   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1026-gcp   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1028-aws   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1030-aws   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1030-gcp   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1032-aws   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1032-gcp   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-1035-aws   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-40-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-42-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-51-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-53-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-59-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.3.0-62-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.4.0-1024-gcp   deinstall
linux-image-5.4.0-1025-aws   deinstall
linux-image-5.4.0-1025-gcp   deinstall
linux-image-5.4.0-1057-gcp   install
linux-image-5.4.0-1059-aws   install
linux-image-5.4.0-1060-aws   install
linux-image-5.4.0-42-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.4.0-90-generic   deinstall
linux-image-5.4.0-91-generic   install
linux-image-aws     install
linux-image-gcp     install
linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04   install
linux-image-gke     install
linux-image-kvm     install
linux-image-oem     install
linux-libc-dev:amd64    install
linux-libc-dev:i386    install
linux-libc-dev-arm64-cross   install
linux-modules-4.15.0-1055-gke   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1056-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1058-gke   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1059-gke   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1059-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1060-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1063-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1063-gke   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1064-gke   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1066-gke   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1067-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1069-gke   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1069-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1070-gke   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1071-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1074-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1075-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1076-oem   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1079-gke   install
linux-modules-4.15.0-1080-oem   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1081-oem   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1087-oem   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1091-oem   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1093-oem   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1096-oem   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1097-oem   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1102-kvm   deinstall
linux-modules-4.15.0-1103-kvm   install
linux-modules-5.0.0-1033-gcp   deinstall
linux-modules-5.0.0-23-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.0.0-37-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1017-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1018-gcp   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1019-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1020-gcp   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1023-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1026-gcp   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1028-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1030-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1030-gcp   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1032-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1032-gcp   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-1035-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-28-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-40-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-42-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-51-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-53-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-59-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.3.0-62-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.4.0-1024-gcp   deinstall
linux-modules-5.4.0-1025-aws   deinstall
linux-modules-5.4.0-1025-gcp   deinstall
linux-modules-5.4.0-1057-gcp   install
linux-modules-5.4.0-1059-aws   install
linux-modules-5.4.0-1060-aws   install
linux-modules-5.4.0-42-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.4.0-47-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.4.0-48-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.4.0-90-generic   deinstall
linux-modules-5.4.0-91-generic   install
linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-23-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-37-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-1018-gcp  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-1020-gcp  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-1026-gcp  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-1030-gcp  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-1032-gcp  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-28-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-40-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-42-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-51-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-53-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-59-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-62-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1024-gcp  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1025-gcp  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1057-gcp  install
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-42-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-47-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-48-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-90-generic  deinstall
linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-91-generic  install
linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04   install
linux-sound-base    install
...
```

Comment: Is it Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Yes, it is:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release: 18.04
Codename: bionic

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dpkg -s inux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1059-aws | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: That did not work, as it says, the package is not installed (I executed the line in the normal ubuntu start-up 5.4.0-1059-aws).
I added the output of sudo dpkg --get-selections and it is not shown there either

Comment: Why are you trying to use the non-generic kernels for an actual end user hardware device?  None of the non-generic kernels are going to function properly with your system, you should be using the generic kernels, NOT the aws/gke/oem/kvm/etc. specific ones.

Comment: It was not my decision, I think. 
I just updated my system and it installed the aws versions.
It did not even tell me, what it is going to update.

Answer (score 0):

> My current workaround is to manually select the 5.4.0-1057-gcp version
> in the boot menu

Please do so and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1059-aws
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-1060-aws
```

Reboot normally and tell us if your touchpad, wifi, ethernet, etc. are now working.

Comment: ALSO a question for OP that still needs answered: why are they using AWS kernels which are not built for end-user devices by default?

Comment: I tried that, but that doesn't seem to work:
E: The repository 'cdrom://Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190805) bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

Comment: The other two lines seem to have worked.
Now mousepad and ethernet are working again.
Bluetooth and Wi-Fi not.
The Software Updater now also tells me, that I could upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. Should I try this?

Comment: So that no aws or gcp kernels are utilized, I recommend that you perform a good backup and then do a fresh install of 20.04 LTS. http://www.releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/

Comment: AWS and GCP kernels are designed for AWS instances or Google Compute instances.  Neither are suited for the enduser devices, so however you installed the system in the first place did it wrong or you did some command from somewhere else that in turn broke your proper kernel versions.

Comment: Okay, many thanks for all your help and for the information. I will work with my workaround for now, because it took me so long in the first place to get the whole system running with the Wi-Fi drivers and some other important stuff not working.